# Would this be a specific example of a tautology? $\neg p\vee(p\vee q)$.

Tags: logic

I have an example, $\neg p\vee(p\vee q)$ would this proposition be considered a tautology according to the truth table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\neg p\vee(p\vee q)\Leftrightarrow (\neg p\vee p)\vee q\Leftrightarrow \text{True}\vee q\Leftrightarrow \text{True}$

Hence it is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline p & q & \neg p & p\vee q & \neg p\vee(p\vee q) \\ \hline 
\color{green}1 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 \\
\hline \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 \\
\hline \color{#C00}0 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 \\
\hline \color{#C00}0 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{green}1 &\color{#C00}0 &\color{green}1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Hence, by definition, it follows that $\neg p\vee(p\vee q)$ is a tautology.